# React variable include another variable?

Tags: reactjs, loops, for-loop

i am doing this code to shorten my coding using React. Especially the list of variables that is redundant.

Here is my coding:

```
let t;
for(t = 1; t <= 5 ; t ++){
    var a = var "dataContent_1_0_0" + t;

    a[1];

    console.log(a);
    };
```

Here are the error which is shown

[image]

Any solutions guys?

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Instead embed it directly into your post with the appropriate markup.

Comment: Owh ok. I ll re-edit it

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = {}; for(t=1; t<=5; t++){ a["dataContent_1_0_0_" + t] = "your-value" } console.log(a)
```

You can use `a.your-dynamic-prop-name` to access the values later. Or you can use object as array also to access the value like `a["your-dynamic-key"+i ]` also to access the values of dynamic properties in another loop.